# Batch process videos from a folder to: remove audio and slow the speed to 0.5x

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor, editing, slowmotion

I have 50 videos all in the same folder and I know FFMPEG is frequently used for this type of work. I would like to learn how to navigate ffmpeg but if there are other free softwares I don't mind using those. I would prefer working in the command line to slow down videos mainly. Audio is less important but a nice to have.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Slow down and no audio command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -filter:v "setpts=2.0*PTS" \
       -an \
       output.mkv
```